# Sybase IQ: Granting a right on tables of one user to anther user

Tags: triggers, sql-grant, rights, sap-iq

I'm looking for a way to **grant some right** (say SELECT) **on all tables** of **one user to** some **other user**.
Something like that:

```
GRANT SELECT ON Username1.* to Username2
```

Important condition is that I need **not only** granting the right to **all existing tables**, but I also want, that **all tables** that **will be created** by Username1 **by default should be granted** with correspondent right to Username2

What I've done is creation a an external script for choosing all tables created by Username1:

```
SELECT table_name FROM systable WHERE creator IN (SELECT user_id from sysuser WHERE username='Username1'))
```

and generating GRANT statements for every of them.

But than I need to execute that script as soon as new table is created. 
It is not really elegant to have that granting logic out of the database. 
I would prefer having kind of trigger within the database, but Sybase IQ does not support triggers.

Anybody have idea how to solve the problem in elegant manner?

Comment: Have you looked at groups, to see if users in the same group can access the newly created tables?

Comment: Unfortunately not. And that concerns not only users in the same group: even if a table is owned by the group itself, members of the group don't get access rights to that table by default.

Comment: this is impossible now, maybe something will be changed int IQ 16